# NSPoint offset by pixels toward angle?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Let me just start with the code.

```
- (NSPoint*) pointFromPoint:(NSPoint*)point withDistance:(float)distance towardAngle:(float)angle; {
    float newX = distance * cos(angle);
    float newY = distance * sin(angle);

    NSPoint * anNSPoint;
    anNSPoint.x = newX;
    anNSPoint.y = newY;

    return thePoint;
}
```

This *should*, based on my knowledge, be perfect. It *should* return and `x` value of `0` and a `y` value of `2` if I call this code.

```
somePoint = [NSPoint pointFromPoint:somePoint withDistance:2 towardAngle:90];
```

Instead, I get and `x` value of `1.05` and a `y` of `1.70`.  How can I find the `x` and `y` coordinates based on an angle and a distance?

Additional note: I have looked on math.stackexchange.com, but the formulas there led me to this. I need the *code*, not the normal math because I know I will probably screw this up.

Comment: NSPoint isn't a class. Why are you showing it as one in your code samples?

Comment: I did that because I am using a custom class. I guess I should have double checked that this code was accurate first :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A working version of your function, which accepts values in degrees instead of radians, would look like this:

```
- (NSPoint)pointFromPoint:(NSPoint)origin withDistance:(float)distance towardAngle:(float)angle
{
    double radAngle = angle * M_PI / 180.0;
    return NSMakePoint(origin.x + distance * cos(radAngle), point.y + distance * sin(radAngle));
}
```

Comment: This is bad. Angles in computer programs are nearly universally represented in radians. You should only accept degrees if you have a *really* good reason to, and if you do, you need to reflect the fact that it's degrees in the name, e.g. `-pointFromPoint:withDistance:towardAngleInDegrees:`. Anything else is a disservice to anyone who has to maintain your code, including you 6 months from now.

Comment: Fair point. The OP specified the results he expected from passing a 90-degree angle into his function, though, so while radians may be more appropriate in general, this does answer his question.

Comment: Many Cocoa classes, like NSBezierPath, use degrees.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is you're giving the angle in degrees (e.g. `90`), but the math is expecting it in radians. Try replacing the `90` with `M_PI_2`

Comment: That is perfect. But how do I make it work with real numbers?

Comment: What do you mean, real numbers? M_PI_2 is just a constant that's defined as half of Pi. You can use any number you want as long as it's expressed in radians. If you need to convert degrees to radians you can use `radians = degrees * M_PI / 180`

Comment: Multiply the degrees input by <code>PI/180</code> to get it in radians.